# Install Ubuntu - "Device for bootloader installation"

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

From my understanding, the Grub2 bootloader can be installed on **any** EFI System Partition (ESP), specifically under `\EFI\ubuntu`.

I have 2 SSDs - with 3 ESP on each of them (for testing purpose):

- `/dev/sda` has `sda1`, `sda3`, `sda5` as ESP
- `/dev/sdb` has `sdb1`, `sdb3`, `sdb5` as ESP

I wasted my time last night only to test the following scenarios for this bootloader installation option:

- Mount `/dev/sda2` as root `/` and select the same device, eg: `/dev/sda` for bootloader installation
- Mount `/dev/sda2` as root `/` and select the ESP on the same device, eg: `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda3`, `/dev/sda5` for bootloader installation
- Mount `/dev/sda2` as root `/` and select a different device, eg: `/dev/sdb` for bootloader installation
- Mount `/dev/sda2` as root `/` and select the ESP on a different device, eg: `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb3`, `/dev/sdb5` for bootloader installation

[image: img]
(image for illustration purpose, not my real test case)

No matter what I select, the bootloader (`\EFI\ubuntu`) is always installed on the first ESP of `/dev/sda` drive - the `sda1`. Edit: even when I mount `sdb2` as root `/` and choose `sdb` for bootloader installation, the bootloader is still installed on `/dev/sda1`, meaning if I remove the 1st SSD, the system won't be able to boot!

What is the point of this option if it always choose the first ESP partition found on the system anyway?

Comment: I think you need to mount the desired ESP at `/boot/efi` and then run `sudo grub-install`, that should install the bootloader on the chosen ESP. In EFI-mode the boot-loader will always be installed to the ESP mounted at `/boot/efi`, thus you normally don't need to specify a device. If no ESP is mounted, the system will search and use the first found ESP.

Comment: While you may have multiple FAT32 partitions to use as ESP - efi system partition, only one per drive can be an ESP at a time. Grub correctly installs to ESP you specify, but Ubiquity installer does not use any info you give it during install, so grub never knows  Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Before work around and if I wanted grub on flash drive, I copied /EFI/ubuntu & /EFI/Boot to flash drive's ESP. Same with sdb's ESP, but also had to use efibootmgr to add UEFI entry.

Comment: Thanks you 2 for your answer. Looks like it is a bug of the Ubiquity installer. I decided to switch to Lubuntu for a change. The Calamares installer and LXQt look much more friendly.